# How Do You Concatenate Arrays In Actionscript 3 When Using Different Image Files?

Tags: actionscript-3

I've looked everywhere on the web to see if I could find an answer to this and I've looked throughout the Adobe Flash Builder help site too and I can't seem to find a concrete answer for what I'm trying to do.

It is possible to reference an array inside of an image file name, here's the scenario.

I have a list of images that only differ by the number at the end of the name (for example. orangeimg1.jpg, appleimg2.jpg, strawberryim3.jpg, etc. Is it possible when referencing the image that I could somehow reference the array in the file name rather than repeating the same code over and over again?

I have two different arrays set up one for fruit which has (orange, apple, stawberry) and I have another array with the numbers (1, 2, 3). I have jpg images for each of these combinations but how to I reference that in one line when I'm trying to refer to these images. I thought something like `source = "[fruit].img.[number].jpg"` would work but I'm a newbie so I'm pretty sure that isn't right.

Again I've found some information on the web but it doesn't refer to how it would work if I was coding a source for my images.

I'm really confused and would appreciate any help with this. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you mark the answer as the correct answer if it was what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are concatenated using `+`.

```
var fruits:Array = ["banana", "cherry"];
var numbers:Array = [4, 2];
var source = fruits[0] + "img" + numbers[0] + ".jpg";  // bananaimg4.jpg
```

If you want to create multiple file names, you can use a loop:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i<fruits.length; i++) {
    var source = fruits[i] + "img" + numbers[i] + ".jpg";
    // ...
}
```

You probably don't need that numbers array. If those numbers are in order you could calculate the number in the loop:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i<fruits.length; i++) {
    var source = fruits[i] + "img" + (i+1) + ".jpg";
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Kapep, I thought I was on the right track, I just wasn't sure how to put it together. Thank you.

Comment: Please use the separate variable for the fruits array length. If we will use the length property calling in for loop conditions then each and every time it will be call and we will get same result. So before for loop we have to declare one "uint" variable and we have to store the length of array in it. So we can optimize for loop performance....

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is good but i am giving only some changes to make code more effective.
We can use for loop in given below format. it's optimized code:

```
var len:uint = fruits.length;
for(var i:int = 0; i<len; i++) {
        var source = fruits[i] + "img" + (i+1) + ".jpg";
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: I say that's micro optimisation here. I'm sure there is no measurable difference in speed, as he won't create a many thousands of file names each frame. Actually loading the image will always be significantly slower. Though, it sure is good to know that style exists for critical parts of the application.